# Idiomatic Traversal Binary Tree (Perhaps Any Tree)

Tags: algorithm, binary-tree, tree-traversal

A Doubly Linked List enables idiomatic traversal of a Linked List and I thought why not for a Binary Tree?  Traditionally, Binary Trees or Trees ingeneral are unidirectional and that implies, given a large tree with sufficient number of nodes, the running time to find a leaf node can be costly.

If, after finding such a node, to find the next I could traverse the tree back toward the root, would that not be advantageous as compared to another depth-first search through every node of the tree?  I have never considered this before until realizing the marriage of a Doubly Linked List and a Binary Tree could potentially add benefit.

For example, if I employed an inner class

```
class Tree<T> {

      private class TwoWayNode {

           var data     : T
           var left     : TwoWayNode
           var right    : TwoWayNode
           var previous : TwoWayNode
      }
}
```

The use of left and right are as normal to traverse the respective subtrees from each node and previous would hold a pointer to the parent node enable idiomatic traversal.  Would someting like this work well and what are some of the potential problems or pitfalls?

Answer (score 1):

Given you store a `previous` reference, you can walk leftmost first. Upon arrival at the leaf node, you back one up again, traverse right.

You can always compare the *current* node, your "walker", with the child nodes, so you can check if you went *left* or *right* the last time. This makes your traversal stateless and you do not even need recursion; suitable for very large datasets.

Now, everytime you just left the right leaf, you back one up again.

This algorithm is a Depth-First-Search.<sup>*</sup>

***Making it faster:***
Given that you could define some deterministic condition for the order of traversal, this can become quite flexible, and even be used in applications like ray tracing.

---

<sup>*</sup>: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Depth-first_search

Bonus: This paper on traversal algorithms for Kd-trees in Ray Tracing: *Review: Kd-tree Traversal Algorithms for Ray Tracing* (http://dcgi.felk.cvut.cz/home/havran/ARTICLES)/cgf2011.pdf

Answer (score 0):

Indeed nodes of a binary tree are often implemented with pointers to the *left* and *right* child and the *parent* (see [this implementation](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.109.4875) of red black trees).

But you not always need a parent pointer:

- For an inorder-traversal you can use a recursive algorithm so that the call stack takes care of that for you.
- If you want to access the *min* or *max* node you can simply maintain a extra pointer to them.
- Sometimes you can use a [finger tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finger_search_tree).
- Or organize your pointers extra clever (see [Self adjusting binary search trees](http://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=3835) page 666):

  - The left pointer of a node points to the first (left) child
  - The right pointer of a node points to either the sibling (if it is a left child) or back to the parent (if it is a right child)

**Extra cool:** [Threaded](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree) binary search trees for extra easy inorder (and reverse order) traversal *without a stack - so O(1) space!*